# convert C structure to matlab structure

Tags: matlab

i want to ask if there is a simple method to convert C/C++ structure to  a MATLAB structure (mxArray*)

i have a mex file which returns a complex C/C++ structure of vectors and i want to get this as output (mxArray*)

i found the mxCreateStructArray method but its not practical in a complex structures

i am using MATLAB 7.11.0

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not such simple method. You need to use mxCreateStructArray, mxAddField, etc methods and create the Matlab struct field by field.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/239457